# foreach перебор содержимого файла

Tags: php

Почему не работает конструкция:

```
<?php
$user = 'user2';
$lines = file('users.txt');
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if ( $line == $user ) {
        echo $line;
        break;
    }   
}
?>

Структура users.txt:
user1
user2
user3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Почему не работает конструкция*

Скорее всего потому, что `file('users.txt')` сохраняет в переменную `$lines` массив строк  с окончанием `\r\n` *(или* `\n` *)*. Вам помогут флаги: `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`:

```
$user = 'user2';
$lines = file('users.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if ( $line == $user ) {
        echo $line;
        break;
    }
}
```